# BackboneJS, RequireJS - Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a Backbone applications where I use RequireJS. Somehow I allways get the **Error**-message `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, so I guess I'm not loading my libraries correctly.

my RequireJS config looks like:

```
require.config({

paths: {

    // Core libraries.
    jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery',
    backbone: 'lib/backbone/backbone',

    // Templating.
    handlebars: 'lib/handlebars/handlebars',

    // Plugins.
    text : 'lib/requirejs-text/text',
    less: 'lib/require-less/less',
    lodash: 'lib/lodash/lodash.min',
    all: 'lib/all/all',
    imageload: 'lib/imageload/jquery.imagesloaded',
    selectivizr: 'lib/selectivizr/selectivizr-min',
    modernizr: 'lib/modernizr/modernizr.min',
    jqueryEffects: 'lib/jquery/jquery.effects',

    // App folders.
    collections: 'app/collections',
    models: 'app/models',
    routers: 'app/routers',
    templates: 'app/templates',
    views: 'app/views'
},

shim: {
    backbone: {
        deps: ['jquery', 'lodash', 'all', 'selectivizr', 'modernizr', 'less', 'jqueryEffects'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    lodash: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    handlebars: {
        exports: 'Handlebars'
    }
}
});
```

I placed the `<script data-main="js/config" src="js/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>` inside the `<body>`-tag of my index page.

So whats the issue here?

Comment: which line of code gives you the error?

Comment: @SHT : jQuery isnt loaded before the execution of your script,that's why you are getting $ undefined error.Make sure jquery is loaded before you executing anything afterwards.

Comment: @SumodhNair Hmm exactly, but I thought jQuery was already loaded, so I dont really know what to change here...

Comment: Hmm ok, when I remove most of the scripts i included in the `shim: {backbone:{deps:[]}}` - the error disappears... But even though, jQuery is always loaded as first script, I dont get it... weird

Comment: @SHT jqueryEffects looks like a jQuery plugin. If it is a jQuery plugin then where is it ensured that jQuery is loaded *before* jqueryEffects? Either jqueryEffects would have to be aware of AMD and call ``define`` by itself or you'd have to set a shim for it like ``jqueryEffects: { deps: [ 'jquery'] }``.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RequireJS - custom js-library not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309911/requirejs-custom-js-library-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

You are getting this error because you are using something that requires jQuery and you have not loaded jQuery before that.

You might have loaded the jQuery but it seems that it has not loaded at proper time.

You have used many plugins so add shim configuration to all Non-AMD plugins those use the jQuery.

Check out which jquery plugin is loaded before jquery so that you can get to root cause.