# RequireJS - custom js-library not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm trying to include a custom js-library/script in my RequireJS-config but it doesnt seem to work. So I hope someone can help me out. I'm using RequireJS in combination with Backbone and Handlebars, so just to mention it...

In my Require config I have:

```
require.config({

paths: {

    jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery',
    backbone: 'lib/backbone/backbone',

    // Templating.
    handlebars: 'lib/handlebars/handlebars',

    // Plugins.
    jqueryEffects: 'lib/jquery/jquery.effects',
    ... //some more libraries

},

shim: {
    backbone: {
        deps: ['jquery', 'lodash','jqueryEffects'],
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    lodash: {
        exports: '_'
    },
    handlebars: {
        exports: 'Handlebars'
    },
    jqueryEffects : {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
  }
});
```

The `jquery.effects.js` is a simple script i created my own to handle special click events or run animations etc. When i start to run my backbone app, the console tells me that the script is loaded. So now on one of my Views, I have rendered a HTML file which contains an anchor with a class which serves as an identifier, which after clicking it should trigger something...BUT, nothing happens, so I tried to make an alert in the `jquery.effects.js`-file:

```
$(function() {
 alert($(".videoname").lenght);
});
```

This gave me the response `undefined`. Does anyone maybe have an idea? The same goes when I add more libraries, console says they are loaded, but nothing happens... ?!?!?!??

Answer (score 1):

try this (length not lenght) :

```
(function() {
    alert($(".videoname").length);
})();
```

That's means that your script is working ;)

Comment: Ha you were right! I misspelled... Now I get the value `0`, and after I clean the cache, it says `$ not defined` (that is a general problem of mine)

Comment: Can you add the jquery.effects.js full code to your question ?

Comment: Or you can use it as a require.js module :
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    alert($(".videoname").length);
});